# how can I get more than one element from json using jsonpath?

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I have a simple  JSON and I would like to get two properties :

`core` and `matching` and verify if `core : true` and `matching : true`.

```
   {

  "lockVersion" 
    : 1,

    "updatedBy" : "jan",

    "updatedOn" : "2016-09-25T11:21:45Z",

    "id" : 964,

    "title" : "Corporate Numeric",

    "description" : null,

    "descType" : 31084140,

    "descValueType" : 31084136,

    "defaultSourceOfVerification" : "Source",

    "core" : true,

    "matching" : true,

    "anything" : 
    [

    ],

  "authorized" 
    : 
    [
         1 
    ]


}
```

Is it possible to do this using AND operator or must I perform a two step action to extract one set then filter again to get my final results?
I'm going to use jp@gc - JSON Path Assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your JSON Path Assertion as follows:

- JSON Path: `[?($.core == true && $.matching == true)]`
- Tick `Validate against expected value` box
- Expected value: `[]`
- Tick `Invert Assertion` box

[image: JMeter JSON Path Assertion]

References:

- [JSON Path Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [JSON Path Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

See [Dmitri T answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46519809/460802) for JSON Path Assertion plugin.

So Using Core JMeter you can do it like this using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) with scope "**JMeter Variable**":

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @The nice downvoters, can you put a comment on why you downvoted ? I still love you :-)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the BeanShell assertion and the built-in JSON parser to achieve this.

```
import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;


try {

    // Use JSONParser to parse the JSON
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(JSONParser.ACCEPT_NON_QUOTE|JSONParser.ACCEPT_SIMPLE_QUOTE); 
    JSONObject rootObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString());

    if ( rootObject.get("matching") && rootObject.get("core") ) {
         Failure=false;
    }
    else {
         Failure=true;
    }


}
catch ( Exception ex) {
    log.info("Exception.." + ex);
     Failure=true;
}
```